# How do I switch default root authorization app?

Tags: 10.04, sudo, gksu

Somehow I've messed everything up and when I open a program like `time-admin` and click "Click to make changes", it uses a Qt / KDE style interface rather than the Gtk style. 
[image]

Running `gksudo AppNameHere` in the terminal works fine and gives me the normal interface for root authorization.
[image]

How can I make it where I always get the Gtk interface for entering the password again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The policykit dialogs are unrelated to gksu.
You will have to purge the package:

```
    polkit-kde-1
```

The gtk+ dialog comes from package:

```
    policykit-1-gnome
```

if you accidentally removed it while installing KDE.

Comment: I've never installed KDE. Polkit-kde-1 isn't installed, and policykit-1-gnome is.

Comment: Nevertheless, this is the root of your problem: The policykit subsystem picks the KDE-dialogs instead of the GTK-ones; you will have to undo some of the changes, maybe reinstalling policykit-1-gnome will help.